# Calculation of coefficient of x

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

What is the *coefficient of $x$* in **$x^{-1}$** ? This question has been asked in an interview.

Comment: Not the exponent ... I would try zero ?

Comment: But if  $-1 < x < 0$ we can write  $${1\over x} = {1\over (x+1) - 1} = - {1\over 1-(x+1)} = -1 - (x + 1) - (x+1)^2 - ...$$ right ?

Comment: I think Donald's right: it is zero, since $\;x^{-1}=\frac1x=\frac1x+0\cdot x\;$ ....I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Provided $|1-x| \le 1$ i.e. $0 < x \le 2$, we can say
$$x^{-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}$$
$$=1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2+(1-x)^3+ \ldots$$

Now compute the coefficient of $x$ from the above expansion.

The answer will be

> $$-\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n} r$$

Comment: I don't think the above makes much sense: the coefficient in that, even assuming that's what the OP meant (and I doubt it as this was a question in an *interview*) is a divergent number series...

Comment: -1* (infinity)  ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree but this is what can be done at max... perhaps answer to the question required some interpretation of the conclusion you gave...

Comment: @OshoAgyeya Its called a divergent sum. See if it helps you in any way.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Why do you think this is what can be done at max? Why not go for the simpler $\;x^{-1}=\frac1x=\frac1x+0\cdot x\implies 0\;$ is the coefficient?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well this is nice, it surpassed my thoughts... It can be so, nothing technically wrong about it. But sounds too elementary and childish to be asked in an interview..

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Sometimes interview's questions are really childish and elementary. Perhaps they want to know how well can one manage with that basic stuff...

Comment: @DonAntonio ... google Grandi's Divergent Formula ... go with Schrodinger's solution the answer is 1/12 ... Honestly if someone said that to me in an interview I would not be able stop myself howling with laughter.

Comment: Both solutions have a good argument for them, but seeing as how a domain restriction wasn't given in the question, (so I assume that $x \in \mathbb {R}$)  I would have to lean towards the answer provided by Donald

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit That'd be quite a stretch of what a reasonable answer in an interview is, or can be... **unless** otherwise stated at the beginning. The sum of all the integers is not more equal to $\;-\frac1{12}\;$ than two plus two equals a roasted duck... *under the usual rules, laws, axioms, etc. of mathematics* .

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit There are times when the regularization of a divergent series is appropriate... and there are times when they are not.  Things of the form $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^Na_k$$ generally should not be regularized like so.