# Solving algebraic equation with nth power.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

I am a student of physics, stuck with the general solution of an algebraic equation of the form:
$$x^{n+2} + x^2 =f$$
I asked Mathematica, she couldn't solve it.

Is there any way to get a general solution for this type of equation (may be in terms some special function) in Mathematics literature?

Please forgive me, if the question is too naive!

Comment: You can't solve it in general.  If $n$ is odd, then let $y=x^2$, which simplifies it.  Else, resort to numerical methods.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Shouldn't that be when $n$ is even? Still, that won't give a general solution.

Comment: @wythagoras Oops, yes, $n$ should read as even.

Comment: But, $y=x^2$, doesn't seem to do much help. or maybe I am not seeing it!

Comment: Well, it might simplify the problem down to a solvable one, though usually not.

Comment: @wythagoras I would not argue with SBA ... You might be told about inappropriate uses of regularisation schemes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174908/calculation-of-coefficient-of-x ... $\ddot \smile$

Comment: The equation can be solved in terms of radicals (using the standard results of Galois theory) for $n=-8,-6,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,4,6$ otherwise you will (as Simply Beautiful Art says) have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: Another approach is to look for some approximate/perturbative result, e.g. $x$ for small values of $f$. That's a common tactic in physics.

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is small, you can use the usual polynomial tricks.  If $n,x$ are large enough $x^{n+2}$ will be much larger than $x^2$.  A good approximation to the solution will then be $x=f^{1/(n+2)}$.  You can then do fixed point iteration using $x_{i+1}=(f-x_i^2)^{1/(n+2)}$ and iterate to convergence.